# Using PHP to interpret BBCode, but unable to use str_replace

Tags: php, parsing, str-replace, bbcode

I'm currently using a PHP class to interpret BBCode that is entered via a form, so that it displays correctly on a user's page when they visit their page.

However I've hit a snag with the conversion from BBCode to HTML as I would ideally like it to convert the following

```
[wiki]Article Title Here[/wiki]
```

to

```
<a href="http://example.com/article_title_here">Article Title Here</a>
```

but it currently only converts to

```
<a href="http://example.com/article title here">Article Title Here</a>
```

I've tried using str_replace to repace the spaces with underscores, but it doesn't seem to want to work for me at the current time.

I've posted the code below for reference, and if it helps at all, I am currently running PHP 7.0.4.

```
    <?php
class bbcode {
    public static function tohtml($text,$advanced=FALSE,$charset='utf-8'){
        $basic_bbcode = array(
            '[b]', '[/b]',
            '[i]', '[/i]',
            '[u]', '[/u]',
        );
        $basic_html = array(
            '<b>', '</b>',
            '<i>', '</i>',
            '<u>', '</u>',
            '<s>', '</s>',
        );
        $text = str_replace($basic_bbcode, $basic_html, $text);
        if ($advanced){
            $advanced_bbcode = array(
                '#\[wiki](.+)\[/wiki]#Usi',
                '#\[email]([\w\.\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.?[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.\w{1,4})\[/email]#Usi',
                '#\[email=([\w\.\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.?[a-zA-Z0-9\-]*\.\w{1,4})](.+)\[/email]#Usi',
                '#\[img](.+)\[/img]#Usi',
                '#\[img=(.+)](.+)\[/img]#Usi',
                '#\[code](\r\n)?(.+?)(\r\n)?\[/code]#si',
                '#\[youtube]http://[a-z]{0,3}.youtube.com/watch\?v=([0-9a-zA-Z]{1,11})\[/youtube]#Usi',
                '#\[youtube]([0-9a-zA-Z]{1,11})\[/youtube]#Usi',
            );
            $advanced_html = array(
                '<a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/$1">$1</a>',
                '<a href="mailto: $1">$1</a>',
                '<a href="mailto: $1">$2</a>',
                '<img src="$1" alt="$1" />',
                '<img src="$1" alt="$2" />',
                '<div class="code">$2</div>',
                '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="width: 450px; height: 366px;" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/$1"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/$1" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /></object>',
                '<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="width: 450px; height: 366px;" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/$1"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/$1" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /></object>',
            );
            $text = preg_replace($advanced_bbcode, $advanced_html,$text);
        }
        return bbcode::nl2br($text);
    }
    public static function remove($text){
        $text  = htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES,$charset);
        return $text;
    }
    public static function nl2br($var){
        return str_replace(array('\\r\\n','\r\\n','r\\n','\r\n', '\n', '\r'), '<br />', nl2br($var));
    }
}
?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The *white space* may be utf-8 encoded. Inspect your existing string using `echo bin2hex($url)` to figure out what bytes it contains.
You can also try this:

```
str_replace("\xE2\x80\xAF", "_", $url)
```

This is replacing a **ZERO-WIDTH SPACE** (UTF-8 encoding `E2 80 AF`) with underscore.